# Troubles porting C++ SDL to Derelict3 in D (D)

Tags: sdl, d

I've gotten Derelict3 working under DMD 2.xx but now I'm having trouble porting my SDL code from C++ to D, the following code gives me this error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Kevin Kowalczyk\My Documents\Code\D\Snippets\Dereli
DL>dmd main.d
main.d(14): Error: undefined identifier SDL_SetVideoMode
main.d(14): Error: undefined identifier SDL_HWSURFACE
main.d(14): Error: undefined identifier SDL_DOUBLEBUF
main.d(15): Error: undefined identifier SDL_WM_SetCaption
main.d(21): Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (SDL_Quit) of type ex
n (C) void function() nothrow to uint
main.d(20): Error: non-final switch statement without a default is deprecated
```

This is the code:

```
import std.stdio;

import derelict.sdl2.sdl;

pragma(lib, "DerelictSDL2.lib");
pragma(lib, "DerelictUtil.lib");

SDL_Surface Surf_Display;
bool running = true;

void main() {
    DerelictSDL2.load();
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Derelict3SDL test", null);
    SDL_Event event;

    while(running) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
            case SDL_Quit:
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use this: `pragma(lib, "DerelictSDL2.lib");`, you're making your code unportable!

Comment: what would you suggest instead? @VladimirMatveev

Comment: Use compiler flags and/or perhaps some build system like CMake or plain makefile. For example, under linux system all what is needed to link a library is specify compiler flag like this: `dmd -L-lSDL program_module.d`. It is certainly possible to specify compiler/linker flags in any advanced enough IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derelict3 uses SDL2, which doesn't have those functions/flags.

Here's the new API: http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/CategoryAPI

I *think* your new init code should be:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Derelict3SDL test", 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480,
    SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN|SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

This is completely and utterly untested. I'm just copying code from the [SDL wiki](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_CreateRenderer#flags).

Comment: thank you I'll take a look at this. I feel like this is something I should have known, lol. I'll mark this as correct when I'm able to compile it.

Comment: Now I'm getting it to compile fine but there's errors when I run it, I'm thinking that the window pointer isn't creating the object correctly or something because it's telling me the object is null.